General ExceptionMapper<Throwable> not working for all exceptions in Quarkus
I have implemented following general ExceptionMapper:
@Provider
@JBossLog
public class RestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {

   @Context
   HttpServerRequest request;

   @Context
   SecurityContext securityContext;

   @Context
   UriInfo uriInfo;

   @Override
   public Response toResponse(Throwable exception) {
      final Throwable rootCause = ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(exception);
      log.errorf("General exception: %s", rootCause.getMessage(), rootCause);
      return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
   }
}

And I have implemented following REST resource:
@Path("/process-settings")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class ProcessSettingResource {

    @POST
    @RunOnVirtualThread
    public RestResponse<Object> createProcessSetting(
        @Valid CreateProcessSettingDto processSettingDto,
        @Context UriInfo uriInfo
    ) {
        URI location = uriInfo.getAbsolutePathBuilder()
            .path(String.valueOf(1L))
            .build();

        if (processSettingDto.getProcessInfo().getProcessName().equals("FAIL")) {
            // ResteasyReactiveViolationException is NOT handled by RestExceptionMapper
            throw new ResteasyReactiveViolationException("Process Name is invalid", new HashSet<>());

            // RuntimeException IS handled by RestExceptionMapper
            // throw new RuntimeException("Process Name is invalid");

            // IllegalArgumentException IS handled by RestExceptionMapper
            // throw new IllegalArgumentException("Process Name is invalid");
        }

        return ResponseBuilder.create(Status.CREATED).location(location).build();
    }
}

Can somebody explain me why certain exceptions are not handled by the general ExceptionMapper like ResteasyReactiveViolationException or its super class ConstraintViolationException and some of them are handled by the general ExceptionMapper like RuntimeException, IllegalArgumentException.
Can somebody explain me if this is a bug or a feature?
If it is a feature can you tell me where are these rules written?
UPDATE
Developers from jax-rs component on github have pointed me to the issue which describes the same problem as I have. There is also a PR which should solve the issue for general ExceptionMapper. I do not know currently what this solution does, so I did not do anything.
What I also found out is that Quarkus Resteasy has some predifined ExceptionsMappers for following Exceptions (found when debugging org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.core.RuntimeExceptionMapper):
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException
io.quarkus.security.AuthenticationRedirectException
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
io.quarkus.security.UnauthorizedException
jakarta.validation.ValidationException
io.quarkus.security.ForbiddenException
io.quarkus.security.AuthenticationFailedException
io.quarkus.security.AuthenticationCompletionException


So, if one of the above exceptions or its subclass is thrown then according to specification one of predefined ExceptionMapper will be taken. Currently I have solved it in such a way that I wrap the exception. Another solution is to implement your own ExceptionMapper for exactly specific exception.
Can somebody from quarkus/reasteasy community elaborate this, so that we have also an official way how to tackle such issues.

When RESTEasy encounters with exception of type ResteasyReactiveViolationException, it is processing them internally and not passing to the general ExceptionMapper.
So I think for the above scenario we need to create a custom exception mapper sepecific to ResteasyReactiveViolationException
@Provider
public class ResteasyReactiveViolationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ResteasyReactiveViolationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ResteasyReactiveViolationException exception) {
        // Handle the exception and return a response
        return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();
    }
}


Yes you are right if I define my own ExceptionMapper for ResteasyReactiveViolationException then it functions, but the idea is that I have one general ExceptionMapper where I want to handle all the Exceptions.

please look at my update of the problem if you want to know a little bit more regarding the problem and possible workarounds.
